# Do not display/get event invitations from shared/external calendars in macOS calendar app

Tags: macos, mail.app, calendar, gmail

I have 3 Gmail accounts which I added to macOS Mail and Calendar. Everything works fine so far except that I do not only get invitations to events for my personal email accounts but also for shared calendars that I have access to. So let's say under my Gmail account (m@testcompany.com), I have access to some co-workers calendars (t@testcompany.com, ...). So now I do not only get an Invitation in macOS calendar for events to which I am invited to but also to those that my co-workers are.

How can I disable this feature since it really drives me crazy?

Comment: I have a feeling this would be configured on google’s end (in which case, you could post on webapps SE). Anything helpful at link below? Did you poke around google settings? https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect